# How do I send information with a form_for form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I have two submit buttons both using the same create action in my controller. How can I send information with a form (without the user inputting it)?

Example:

Button 1: Creates a database entry with 1.

Button 2: Creates a database entry with 2.

Comment: You can use hidden field in the form to pass entry 1 or 2 as the data in the form.

Comment: Thanks, put it was an answer and I'll mark it correct. I used this link to get the right syntax: http://bparanj.blogspot.com/2007/06/how-to-use-hidden-field-in-rails.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden field like this:

```
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :entry, 1 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Button 1' %>

<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :entry, 2 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Button 2' %>
```